# RVM says it can't open openssl.cnf

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I'm setting up my new MacBook (10.8.3) with rvm, and I consistently get this:

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /Users/dan/.rvm/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf
```

I looked in that directory, and do not see openssl.cnf. I've tried reinstalling rvm in many different configurations, and I've tried running `rvm pkg install openssl`, but it gives me the same warning.

How can I remedy this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows,  you set a system environment variable

add the variable:
OPENSSL_CONF
then point to the directory where your openssl.cnf file is

That is what fixed my problem for that error message at least.

but for MAC, the variable might be accessed from some other place. I'm not sure if MAC uses the same term or not.